# Javascript require method is not finding axios module

Tags: javascript, axios

I am creating a chrome extension for gmail. I have installed axios using "npm install axios" and that has created a node_modules folder with the module included. I then tried to include the module in my extension.js file but gives "cannot find module 'axios'" error. The axios documentation says "In order to gain the TypeScript typings (for intellisense / autocomplete) while using CommonJS imports with `require()` use the following approach:

```
 const axios = require('axios').default;
```

So i placed it in my extension.js

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
```

The axios location leads to the index.d.ts file. I am not sure why it does not go to the index.js where the

```
module.exports = require('./lib/axios');
```

is located.

package-lock.json

```
{
  "requires": true,
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": {
      "version": "0.21.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/axios/-/axios-0.21.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-dKQiRHxGD9PPRIUNIWvZhPTPpl1rf/OxTYKsqKUDjBwYylTvV7SjSHJb9ratfyzM6wCdLCOYLzs73qpg5c4iGA==",
      "requires": {
        "follow-redirects": "^1.10.0"
      }
    },
    "follow-redirects": {
      "version": "1.13.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/follow-redirects/-/follow-redirects-1.13.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-DUgl6+HDzB0iEptNQEXLx/KhTmDb8tZUHSeLqpnjpknR70H0nC2t9N73BK6fN4hOvJ84pKlIQVQ4k5FFlBedKA=="
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added a solution. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Try:
`npm install axios`

Then:

```
import axios from 'axios'; // ES6 module syntax

// ... or using CommonJS syntax:

const axios = require('axios'); // CommonJS syntax
```

Note: If you still facing same issue please visit following links:

1. [[ts] cannot find module 'axios'](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1221) &
2. https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/940

Comment: I tried this and its giving the same error. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you used the `.default` in your request that's for typescript.

Simply use `const axios = require('axios');`

if it's still not working do `npm i`  again and then `npm i axios` again.

Comment: I removed the .default and installed axios again to no avail . Can you think of any other suggestions?